# Vertx service interface refactor

Tags: java, vert.x

I am using services and the code generator to manage the interface to my database and execute the queries. It's really good, I love this approach but with many queries the implementing class is very long. This is my interface:

```
@ProxyGen
@VertxGen
public interface DatabaseService {

  @GenIgnore
  static DatabaseService create(MySQLPool dbClient, Handler<AsyncResult<DatabaseService>> readyHandler) {
    return new DatabaseServiceImpl(dbClient, readyHandler);
  }

  @GenIgnore
  static DatabaseService createProxy(Vertx vertx, String address) {
    return new DatabaseServiceVertxEBProxy(vertx, address);
  }

  // ====== DESKTOP ====== //

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listNonPreviste(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addNonPreviste(String descr, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteNonPreviste(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editNonPreviste(String id, String value, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService checkDeleteNonPreviste(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Integer>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listModifiche(String anno, String mese, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addModifiche(String operatore, String motivazione, String campo, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listLavorazioni(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addLavorazioni(String descr, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteLavorazioni(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editLavorazioni(String id, String value, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService checkDeleteLavorazioni(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Integer>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listComponenti(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addComponenti(String descr, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteComponenti(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editComponenti(String id, String value, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService checkDeleteComponenti(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Integer>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listRelazioniComponenti(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listNonRelazioniComponenti(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addRelazioniComponenti(String componente, String lavorazione, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteRelazioniComponenti(String componente, String lavorazione, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listOperatori(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addOperatori(String nome, String cognome, String ufficio, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteOperatori(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService checkDeleteOperatori(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Integer>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editOperatori(String id, String field, String value, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listRelazioniOperatori(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listNonRelazioniOperatori(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addRelazioniOperatori(String operatore, String componente, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteRelazioniOperatori(String operatore, String componente, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService totaleOreMeseOperatore(String id, String data, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService riassuntoGiornalieroOperatore(String id, String data, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listCommesseAperte(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listCommesseChiuse(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addCommessa(String codice, String descrizione, String matricola, String quantita, String conclusa, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteCommessa(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService checkDeleteCommessa(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Integer>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editCommessa(String id, String field, String value, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService riassuntoCommessaOre(String commessa, String ufficio, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService riassuntoCommessaLavorazioni(String commessa, String lavorazione, String ufficio, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService riassuntoCommessaComponenti(String commessa, String componente, String ufficio, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService commessaLavorazioniOre(String commessa, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService commessaComponentiOre(String commessa, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listOre(String mese, String anno, String officina, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addOre(List<String> params, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addOreConID(List<String> params, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteOre(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listOreNote(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listOreNonpreviste(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editNote(String testo, String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editOreNonPreviste(String nonprevId, String oraId, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);

}
```

The class `DatabaseServiceImpl` implements the interface and is very very long. Is there any way to "split" this interface? Or somehow have the implementing class "smaller" because it's getting very big.

It's still good because all the database logic is in these 2 files so the DB logic is separated from the rest, but classes are getting big and a bit hard to maintain. Thanks, I am using java 12

---

I have splitted the interface for example like this:

```
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listNonPreviste(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addNonPreviste(String descr, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService deleteNonPreviste(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService editNonPreviste(String id, String value, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService checkDeleteNonPreviste(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<Integer>> handler);

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listModifiche(String anno, String mese, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler);
  @Fluent
  DatabaseService addModifiche(String operatore, String motivazione, String campo, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler);
```

Because there are 2 logical units called "Modifiche" and "Nonpreviste". I'd like to create two classes `Modifiche` and `Nonpreviste` that implement only the methods that I require.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not splitting Interface and its implementation in that similar case becase storage type can be changed and implementation too but methods will be same. Simply devide implementation on commands.

```
DBImpls class {
  NonPrevisteCommands nonPrevisteCommands;
  ModificheComands modificheComands;
 ....

 DBImpls() {
  this.nonPrevisteCommands = new NonPrevisteCommands();
  this.modificheComands = new ModificheComands(); 
  ......
 } 

 DatabaseService listNonPreviste(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler){
  return this.nonPrevisteCommands.listNonPreviste(handler); 
 }

 DatabaseService addNonPreviste(String descr, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler){
  return this.nonPrevisteCommands.addNonPreviste(descr, handler); 
 }
 .....

 DatabaseService listModifiche(String anno, String mese, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler) {
     return this.modificheCommands.listModifiche(descr, handler); 
 }
 ......
}
```